# Raster values outside of expected range

Tags: raster

I got a temperature raster (maximum temperature for January, global extent) and the value range seems to go beyond the valid range. The highest is 42.006 (which I assumed should be Celsius) but the lowest is -9999 (which corresponds to the ocean). The image is attached.

[image]

Comment: It's likely that the -9999 value is a 'no data' value and this dataset doesn't include temperature data for the ocean.

Comment: The -9999 value is a placeholder for NoData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at a NoData value. Taken from the [ArcGIS documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/nodata-in-raster-datasets.htm):

> Cell values can be either positive or negative, integer, or floating
>   point. Cells can also have a NoData value to represent the absence of
>   data. Sometimes there are homogeneous areas in a raster dataset that
>   the you do not want to display. These can include borders,
>   backgrounds, or other data considered to not have valid values.
>   Sometimes these are expressed as NoData values, although other times
>   they may have real values.

If you want to change the color for the NoData pixels you have to specify it in the symbology as follows:

[image]

In case the NoData value is not set go to ArcCatalog or the Catalog window -> Right click on the raster -> Properties and Edit the NoData value.

[image]

Comment: when i change the property "display NoData" it does not affect my raster in any way

Comment: Did you change the color and click *Apply*?

Comment: yes i did. it did not change anything

Comment: I just edited my answer to show you how to edit the NoData value.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Comment: If this answer solved your question feel free to mark it as accepted so the question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the above answer - make sure that -9999 is assigned as the NoData value for the raster dataset.

Go to Layer Properties > Source > NoData value

[image]

Comment: It is not currently assigned and it cannot be changed from the properties window.